# How can I see what date I marked a question as a Favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

As a happy user of stackoverflow.com, I'm opening the list of my Favorites added all over the time and expect to find questions added in the specific period of time, for example, in 2014.

Why have you guys implemented the list of Favorites in that way that I can only see when those questions were **updated** instead of **bookmarked**?

Of course, the sorting order is right, from past to future, in the order when I bookmarked those. But guys, I'm really need to see those addition dates (and please, not question creation dates :-) ).

Comment: You're not going to convince lots of people with such a title. Consider editing to show what is actually the thing you're after here.

Comment: How about changing your question to something a little more constructive? Like *please add a way to sort favourites by time of starring*, or something. Attacking developers and managers on some misplaced assumptions is **not** going to go down well.

Comment: I'm really attacking because your defaults make me assume that there were no thought process at all beside the favorites list implementation. I'm sorry for the angry speech, the unexpected behavior made me really very upset.

Comment: I'm also getting really very upset by posts like yours. Just don't.

Comment: ....or they just decided (rightfully so) that it isn't worth wasting any dev time on something with literally no upside. PS: assuming things is bad.

Comment: @rene I'm very very sorry. Take my apologies for the unprofessional tone. Thank you for the great work. I love stackoverflow.com and expect perfectionism everywhere. It's best designed thing in the world. That's the reason why I become so upset. Managing expectations problem... :-/

Comment: "*I'm really need to see those addition dates*" ... why? Seriously, why does it matter when you favorited a question? What do you intend to do with such information?

Comment: @NicolBolas memory of many people works in temporal space when they trying to find something. It's very easy to recall when something happened. Personally for me, it makes sad sense that many window (app) switching features in many OSes (and tabs in browsers, too) are implemented in that way that they almost completely ignore temporal navigation. Life can be much easier if instead of tabs and taskbars UX designers were using recent lists and switching popping up history instead of windows list on Alt + Tab or Home button double click etc.

Comment: @IvanBorisenko: That doesn't explain why you need to know the *date*. It only explains why you would want to order them by when you added them. Which you can already do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The date on which you favorited the question is not shown in the UI. The tab [*added*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84661/ivan-borisenko?tab=favorites&sort=added) is sorted however on that date. To get that date you have to rely on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I have created the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/630526) for you to include that date:

```sql
select postid as [Post Link] 
     , v.creationdate as [Favorited on]
     , p.creationdate as [Post created]
     , p.lastactivitydate as [Post active]
     , p.score as [Post score]
     , case when p.acceptedanswerid is not null then 'accepted' else null end as [accept]
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
from votes v 
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where userid = 84661
and votetypeid = 5 
order by v.creationdate desc
```

The creationdate in the votes table is sanitized for many votetypes to only include the date and no time information.

When run today this is what the result look likes:

[image]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only update once a week, on Sunday.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, it helps very much! Can you create a feature request to display "Favorited on" field instead of "Post active" field in the favorites tab ( http://stackoverflow.com/users/84661/ivan-borisenko?tab=favorites&sort=added ) when it's sorted by the date favorited on?

Thank you very much for the collaboration! You are the best team in the world!

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of orderings presented as options.  One of which is the date added to favorites.  If you want to see them in that order, then select that order.

Comment: I **see** them in order. I need to see **the date of addition (bookmarking)**!

Comment: @IvanBorisenko are you saying that [this tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84661/ivan-borisenko?tab=favorites&sort=added) isn't sorted according to when you marked the question as favorite because that list is the same order as the [raw data in SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/630526). It might be that we talk about different things.

Comment: @rene the tab **is** sorted according to when I marked the question as favorite. I just want to see when I've marked the question as favorite in the date time field displayed on the right side of the tiles instead of question's **latest update time**, which I'm as a user don't need absolutely when browsing the favorites list.